# Algorithm for Removing Inverted Elements from a Permutation

Tags: co.combinatorics, algorithms, permutations

I currently have a problem, whose solution requires to remove from a permutation of $\lbrace 1,\ \dots,\ n\rbrace$ those values that are to the left of a smaller one.

My idea was to remove the complement of the [longest increasing subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_increasing_subsequence), but am not quite sure, if that yields the correct result (which I doubt, because the longest increasing subsequence need not be unique, whereas the inversion relation is) and/or whether it would be the most efficient way to remove all inversions.

> **Questions:**
>
> - does the longest increasing subsequence of a permutation represent the complement of all inversions?
> - what is the fastest known algorithm for removing all "inverted" elements from a permutation?

Comment: The answer to the first question is certainly "no", as the permutation $[2,3,1,6,4,5]$ shows: in this case, the longest increasing subsequence is even unique, it is $2,3,4,5$.  If I understand correctly, you want to remove $2$,$3$ and $6$, right?

Comment: @MartinRubey yes, you have put it correctly; I want to remove 2,3 and 6. And thanks for the example with unique longest increasing subsequence.

Comment: Find the smallest element $s_1=1$. Find the smallest element $s_2$ that comes after $s_1$; find smallest $s_3$ that comes after $s_2$, etc. until you get $s_k$ equal the last element in the permutation. Then $(s_1,s_2,\dots,s_k)$ is the required subpermutation, isn't it?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev your algorithm will work, but you always would have to search for the next smallest unremoved elemement; could require $O(n^2)$ steps or, you could use a second array with values $[1,\ \dots,\ n]$, in which the removed elements are marked; in that array you could go from left to right to identify the next smallest element and then remove all elements of the primary array until you have encountered the identified next minimal value, requiring $O(n)$ steps.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: So, there is a linear algorithm. What is your question then?

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev the existence of an $O(n)$ algorithm actually answers my question; the only further improvement I see would be an inplace algorithm without requiring the auxiliary arry I have mentioned in previous comment. You could turn your comment into an answer, because that actually reflects the fact that there is an answer to it.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Using a linked list as an auxiliary data structure is much easier. I've explained this in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a doubly-linked list $L$, initially empty. Scan a given permutation $p=(p_1,p_2,\dots,p_n)$ from left to right, and for each element $p_i$ perform the following operations:

1. (loop) While $L$ is not empty and $p_i$ is smaller than the last element of $L$, remove this last element from $L$.
2. Append $p_i$ to $L$.

At the end, $L$ will contain a required subpermutation of $p$. Notice that visiting (i.e., comparison to) every element of $L$ results in either appending or removal of an element to/from $L$. The total number of such operations does not exceed $2n$, since every element of $p$ may be appended to $L$ only once and removed from $L$ only once. So, this is a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: does "last element" denote the element to the left of $p_i$ or the element at the end of the list?

Comment: "last element" refers to the last element of $L$